# Rounding issue for float type in Snowflake

Tags: sql, floating-point, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, rounding

I have two columns (float type) as below:

```
MRR        Standard_MRR
629.0625    687.5
```

I need to do the calculation - (1-MRR/Standard_MRR)=0.085000

If I round the result to 2 decimal place and it will give me 0.08 instead of 0.09. I think it maybe due to float type. So I convert the data type of MRR and Standard_MRR to decimal(20,10) by Cast function. But It still gives me the answer of 0.08 instead of 0.09. How to fix it?

Comment: 1) What is your dbms and version? 2) With simple scenarios like that, you should include a [minimal repro case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Specifically, post an example demonstrating that `...convert(ing) the data type ... to decimal(20,10) ...but It still gives me the answer of 0.08`

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using

Comment: Umm... Round to 3 decimal places instead of 2? `0.085` can't fit in two decimal places, because there are three decimals to the right of the decimal point.

Comment: @KenWhite - I think they meant it rounded differently than expected. i.e. They expected `0.085` to round up to `0.09` but got `0.08` instead, i.e. rounded down

Comment: eric, "If I round the result to 2 decimal place ..." --> Try rounding the calculation result to 30 places to see that the answer is just less than 0.085.  That number rounded to 2 places would then be 0.08.  Note: the number 0.085 is not available as a floating point.  A nearby value is used instead.

Answer (score 1):

### The numbers as presented are fine:

```
SELECT 
    629.0625 as mrr
    , 687.5 as standard_mrr
    , (1-MRR/Standard_MRR) as math_raw
    ,round(math_raw, 2) math_2dp;
```

gives:

| MRR | STANDARD_MRR | MATH_RAW | MATH_2DP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 629.0625 | 687.5 | 0.085 | 0.09 |

### But using more likely values:

The way to handle this is pre-round to +3 DP first, and then round at desired level.

```
SELECT 
    629.06249999 as mrr
    , 687.499999 as standard_mrr
    , (1-MRR/Standard_MRR) as math_raw
    ,round(math_raw, 2) math_2dp
    ,round(math_raw, 2+3) as pre_round
    ,round(pre_round, 2) math_5_2dp;
```

gives:

| MRR | STANDARD_MRR | MATH_RAW | MATH_2DP | PRE_ROUND | MATH_5_2DP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 629.06249999 | 687.499999 | 0.084999998684 | 0.08 | 0.085 | 0.09 |